# Gmail rule "reply with canned response and delete" doesn't work

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-canned-response

I'm trying to set up a Gmail rule which runs whenever I receive an email to a specific address. This rule sends a canned response and then deletes the email.

The rule to send the canned response works great. However as soon as I change the rule to also delete the email then the canned response is not sent. The email is deleted though.

I've tried setting up two separate rules - one that sends the canned response and another which does the deleting - but still no canned response is sent.

Is there any way I can do both?